# Distinct variables for different clauses

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving

In resolution theorem proving, it is normally assumed variables in different clauses are distinct. This is not something that happens automatically; it requires significant extra code and computation to implement. Given that, I'm looking for a test case for it.

The problem is, in all the test cases I've tried so far, it makes no difference. Presumably it matters only in unusual edge cases. As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29) puts it, "variables in different clauses are distinct... Now, unifying Q(X) in the first clause with Q(Y) in the second clause means that X and Y become the same variable anyway."

Are there any known test cases that will actually give the wrong answer if different clauses use the same variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** I found a better example. Consider these clauses:
\begin{align}
& \lnot P(x) \lor P(f(x)) \\
& P(x) \\
& \lnot P(f(f(x)))\\
\end{align}
Obviously, this set of clauses is contradictory. But without renaming variables, the only possible resolvent is $P(f(x))$ and no more resolvents are possible - all lead to substituting $f(x)$ for $x$, which is impossible.

---

**Edit:** Consider the meaning of clauses. Each clause is implicitly universally quantified. So the meaning of its variables isn't fixed to anything. Now let's say you have two clauses both containing $x$. If you perform resolution without renaming $x$ in one of them, then you add a meaning to $x$ which it doesn't have: you say that $x$ means the same thing in both clauses, which is not true.
If you don't have distinct variables in your clauses, resolution will give you too weak conclusions.

---

(The original answer.)
For example, let's have 4 clauses:

1. $A\lor B(x)$
2. $\lnot A\lor C(x)$
3. $\lnot B(c)$
4. $\lnot C(d)$

where $x, y$ are variables and $c, d$ constants. If we perform resolution on the first two without renaming $x$, we'll get $B(x)\lor C(x)$. We can proceed with $\lnot B(c)$ to get $C(c)$ but now we cannot resolve it with $\lnot C(d)$.

On the other hand, if we rename $x$ to $y$ in the second one to have disjoint set of variables, we'll get $B(x)\lor C(y)$ from the first resolution step and we can derive an empty clause using $\lnot B(c)$ and $\lnot B(d)$.

Comment: When I try this in my prover with distinct variables disabled, it resolves $B(x)$ with $\lnot B(c)$ to give $A$, similarly obtains $\lnot A$ and thence the empty clause, so the end result is the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: @rwallace Not having distinct variables doesn't mean you cannot derive the empty clause, just that the methods isn't complete. If you always rename variables then it doesn't matter in which order you pick clauses, you'll always derive the empty clause if the original set is unsatisfiable - the method is complete. But, if you don't rename variables then (as the example shows) the order suddenly matters - some sequences of derivations won't find the empty clause. And, a prover cannot "tell" in advance which sequence of derivations is the proper one.

Comment: But is it not the case that a complete method must eventually try every possible derivation (unless it finds the empty clause first)? To be sure there is no guarantee it will try the derivations I mentioned before the ones you mentioned, but when the ones you mentioned fail because of lack of distinct variables, the ones I mentioned are still open and a complete method must go back and try those sooner or later?

Comment: Your addendum regarding the meaning of clauses in the abstract makes sense, but it seems to me if that is so then it ought to be possible to find a test case, something I can feed into a prover and cause it to give the wrong answer if the distinct variables feature is disabled. I just haven't been able to find such a test case so far.

Comment: @rwallace Why would you want to do that? Resolution is a complete method and you know that under any circumstances it's only necessary to perform resolution on each pair of clauses only once. You suggest to eventually try all possible sequences how to proceed with backtracking. This will result in a _really huge_ increase of the algorithm's complexity, not even remotely comparable with simply renaming variables at each step.

Comment: Oh certainly, I'm not talking about backtracking to repeat resolution on the same pair of clauses. If you look at the derivations I mentioned, they operate on different pairs of clauses than the ones you mentioned. 5=1+3, 6=2+4, empty=5+6. No repeats on any given pair, regardless of order of clause selection.

Comment: @rwallace More advanced resolution techniques such as hyper-resolution or ordered resolution aim the opposite -- to limit the number of possibilities how to reach the goal (while maintaining completeness, of course). Ideally, one would want at each step to have only one choice which clause to pick for resolution. This way, these methods achieve a significant improvement in time complexity. (If I have time I'll try to find an example where resolution without renaming fails in all cases.)

Comment: @rwallace I agree, but what if your (or some other) prover proceeds just in the order given in my example and fails to derive the empty clause? What does it do next? It says that the set is satisfiable (which is not true), or backtracks?

Comment: The order given in your example still leaves some clause pairs unresolved (the ones I listed), so the prover still needs to try those - they will still be on its to-do list without backtracking. But there is a bigger problem, or maybe a bigger confusion on my part...

Comment: Using TPTP format since I don't know how to get for-all in this markup: (![X]: (p(X) & q(X))) <=> ((![X]: p(X)) & (![Y]: q(Y))) - I tried that just now in my prover and in E, and they both say it's a theorem. That seems to suggest even in the abstract it doesn't make any logical difference?

Comment: @rwallace Correct, but clauses are _disjunctions_. While `(![X]: (p(X) | q(X))) => ((![X]: p(X)) | (![X]: q(X)))` is provable, the reverse implication is not! (The right part corresponds to merging two clauses together in the resolution rule with distinct variables, the left part corresponds to merging them without renaming. So not renaming is strictly weaker.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought of first until I remembered individual clauses are disjunctions but sets of clauses are conjunctions! p(X) and q(X) represent entire clauses, not literals. And thinking about it,you say using the same variable name means the variable refers to the same thing in each clause which is not true - but isn't it? There's an implied universal quantifier so the variable in each case means 'anything'.

Comment: (1) Resolution rules ends with merging literals from two distinct clauses. This is where the problem occurs - this is the `|` from my previous comment. (2) The point of resolution is to derive _most generic_ clauses, only then it's complete. I suggest you to study the proof of the completeness of resolution. Surely you can substitute anything for the variables. But you don't want to do that because there is an infinite number of possible substitutions. You want to substitute _just what's necessary_ to make the number of substitutions as small as possible while maintaining completeness.

Comment: Okay, so what you are saying is that the inputs are equivalent, but in the resulting clause, `p(X) | q(Y)` is stronger than `p(X) | q(X)`, which is true - and that could potentially make inference more efficient. But there still isn't a known test case that demonstrates incompleteness without distinct variables?

Comment: @rwallace I believe I found a better example - try it on your prover with distinct variables disabled.

Comment: That does indeed successfully test distinct variables, thanks!